# No Creators, like default constructor, exist, Cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I am getting this error for this class while deserializing the data, any input what I am doing wrong here.  No Creators, like default constructor, exist, Cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

```
 @Getter
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public class Test
{

public Test(String service, String user) {
        this.service = service;
        this.user = user;
    }
   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   
    @JsonProperty("service")
    private String service;

    
    @JsonProperty("user")
    private String user;

    
    @SuppressWarnings("java:S2094")
    public static class Builder
    {
       
    }
}
```

Comment: try by adding a no param constructor. also provide setters and getters

Comment: Looks like you are using Lombok - you should add that tag. And search for "Lombok jackson", you will find plenty of resources. This may also be useful: https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized

Comment: @assylias I've confirmed that the code compiles and produces the given error under your assumptions that this is both Lombok & Jackson, so I've made your suggested edits to the question's tags.

Answer (score 2):

Probably won't help this exact case, but since this is the top search result I'll add this in case it's helpful to others:

It turns out interfaces can complicate things and result in this jackson error. This guide helped me: https://andrewtarry.com/posts/deserialising-an-interface-with-jackson/

Answer (score 1):

Adding the [`@Jacksonized`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized) Lombok annotation to your class got it working for me:

```java
@Getter
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Jacksonized
public class Test {
```

Per the Lombok documentation:

> The `@Jacksonized` annotation is an add-on annotation for [`@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) and [`@SuperBuilder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder). It automatically configures the generated builder class to be used by [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)'s deserialization. It only has an effect if present at a context where there is also a `@Builder` or a `@SuperBuilder`; a warning is emitted otherwise.
>
> Without `@Jacksonized`, you would have to customize your builder class(es). With `@Jacksonized`, you can simply write something like this to let Jackson use the generated builder:
>
> ```java
> @Jacksonized @Builder
> @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
> public class JacksonExample {
>   private List<Foo> foos;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have two variants of what to do:

1. Use `@Builder` instead of `@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")`. Lombok will create the builder name automatically.
2. Add `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@Setter` annotations on the class level.